# Capturing clicking on tab in pre tag works in a strange way

Tags: jquery, tabs, keydown, keycode

I want to catch the click on the tab and insert a tab space.

I put alert in the code to check a certain value and maybe know why it does not work for me and then I found out that the code with the alert work and without the alert doesn't work. Why not, and how can I fix it?

This works for me:

```
$('pre').keydown(function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if (keyCode == 9) {
        alert('test');
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).val($(this).val() + '\t');
    }
});
```

This doesn't work:

```
$('pre').keydown(function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if (keyCode == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).val($(this).val() + '\t');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What is "pre"? Is it a class or id? If it is a class then put `.pre` or if it is id then add `#pre`.

```
$('#pre').keydown(function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if (keyCode == 9) {
        alert('test');
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).val($(this).val() + '\t');
    }
});
```

or

```
$('.pre').keydown(function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if (keyCode == 9) {
        alert('test');
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).val($(this).val() + '\t');
    }
});
```

or you can also use

```
$('.pre').bind('keydown',function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if (keyCode == 9) {
        alert('test');
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).val($(this).val() + '\t');
    }
});
```

Comment: the code is work fine but only if i insert alert to the code and i don't want to insert the alert

Comment: What you want to do? and yes i forget about <pre> tag.

Comment: i want move forward (like in text or code editor) and not move to the next element. (i want to stay on this tag and move forward as you press on space bar)

Comment: Please do code in window.setTimeout() with some time limit 500 because you are saying that your code is working when you put alert() so its means that your actual code need some time to define, so please do your code in window.setTimeout().

Comment: its funny because it also does not work. the code works only if I put alert code. very strange.